# What should one log?

Tags: logging, erlang

I know this seems like a dumb question, but what should I log? I have a distributed, special-purpose cache with Pub/Sub support and am using lager for my logging.

I use Info log-level for life-cycle stuff - server start-up, etc. but I find myself putting Debug-level log lines on nearly every exported function... Just in case I need them... I'm using Warning-level on recoverable trouble items like a node-down...

I googled logging best practices, but what I found seemed to be more about the JVM then logging best-practice.

Is there an Erlang logging best-practice? Or some lessons learned that can be shared?

The logging best practices I have seen seem to be oriented around Java and #/.Net paradigms. I'm asking, given the heavy use of OTP and Erlang / functional idioms, what is the advice on logging? Should I log every handle_X clause, etc?

Comment: I hope this doesn't get moderated out of existence. I am curious what folks might say. It might be easier to get a more full response on the mailing list, though.

Comment: This isn't specific to Erlang, but a general question about what gets logged. I think it would be more appropriate over at https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I mean this to be Erlang specific. I will edit it to make that clear.

Comment: But really I can't see any erlang-specific logging issues. All of them are quite general. Personally I tend to use next rule of thumb (however there can not be any rule of thumb, all depends on your particular application). First of all I log as much as possible. All issues, that can help me with debuging or operations. And then, if amount of logs became enormous, I try to reduce useless messages and replace it with similar numberic metrics that monitoring system can process.

Comment: I agree with Viacheslav: there's nothing Erlang-specific in your updated question. Java and .NET have servers that start up, public functions, and recoverable exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use debug logs in case they might be useful for the server administrator (not for the Erlang developer) to pinpoint problems. I think for the developers the built-in debug & tracing functionality is much more powerful. 
Please have a look at *redbug* it is part of the [eper](https://github.com/massemanet/eper) library and lets you safely debug an online Erlang system.